# How to plot a column from a csv file against a column that doesn't exist in the file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I am pretty new to python and matplotlib using csvfiles. My question is trying to plot the following graph. I'm having an issue with creating the x variable that I need to plot against y, 'doors'. More specifically, I want to be able to plot the number of 'doors' against the car id which can be assumed to be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7... and so on with respect to the entries in the 'doors' columns. Without a specific column already dedicated to car id, how would I go about this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('9car.data.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Have you simply tried anything at all?

Comment: So just read the data that you want from the CSV file and plot it against `range(8)` on the x axis.

Comment: If I remember correctly `plt.plot(y)` plots `y` against a `0` starting range w/o any further ado.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`pyplot.plot` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)

> For example, each of the following is legal:
>
> ```
> plot(x, y)        # plot x and y using default line style and color  
> plot(x, y, 'bo')  # plot x and y using blue circle markers   
> plot(y)           # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1
> ```

Hence something like this would work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('data/estimated.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')    
    y = [float(row[1]) for row in plots]

plt.plot(y)

plt.show()
```

Or even better, using numpy

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x,y = np.loadtxt('data/estimated.csv', delimiter=',',unpack=True)

plt.plot(y)

plt.show()
```